# GNU Octave Vertical Dimensions Mismatch

Tags: octave, dimensions

I've been getting the following error in GNU Octave:

```
error: vertical dimensions mismatch (1x2 vs 1x3) error: called from
ProjectPart1 at line 31 column 4
```

based on this code (in a for/end loop after zeta(:,1)):

```
zeta(:,1)=[sum(beta)/lambda,P0];
N=[-lambda,sum(beta);lambda/gen,(rho-sum(beta))/gen];
zeta(:,i)=zeta(:,i-1)+N*zeta(:,i-1)*dt;
```

I ran this a month-ish ago and I remember it working, any idea why it's not working now?

Edit:
Here's the whole thing. I've tried switching things around, restarting the program, and restarting my computer. Is uninstalling and reinstalling worth it (since one commenter said it worked fine for them)?

```
lam=[0.0128,0.0318,0.119,0.3181,1.4027,3.9286];
beta=[0.000258,0.00152,0.001391,0.00307,0.001102,0.000258];
P0=1e-6;
a=8*sum(beta);
lambda=((beta(1)*lam(1))+(beta(2)*lam(2))+(beta(3)*lam(3))+(beta(4)*lam(4))+(beta(5)*lam(5))+(beta(6)*lam(6)))/sum(beta);
hold off;
box on;
gen=2.6E-5;
dt=.001;
secint=.125/dt;
t(1)=0;
zeta(:,1)=[sum(beta)/lambda,P0];
rho(1)=0
for i=2:secint
N=[-lambda,sum(beta);lambda/gen,(rho-sum(beta))/gen];
zeta(:,i)=zeta(:,i-1)+N*zeta(:,i-1)*dt;
t(i)=t(i-1)+dt;
rho(i)=a*t(i);
end
```

The vertical dimensions error is specifically pointing to this line:

```
N=[-lambda,sum(beta);lambda/gen,(rho-sum(beta))/gen];
```

Comment: We can't run it either unless you give us sample values for all of the undefined variables.

Comment: lam=[0.0128,0.0318,0.119,0.3181,1.4027,3.9286];
beta=[0.000258,0.00152,0.001391,0.00307,0.001102,0.000258];
P0=1e-6;
a=8*sum(beta);
lambda=((beta(1)*lam(1))+(beta(2)*lam(2))+(beta(3)*lam(3))+(beta(4)*lam(4))+(beta(5)*lam(5))+(beta(6)*lam(6)))/sum(beta);

gen=2.6E-5;
dt=.001;

Comment: Works fine for me, assuming `rho` is a scalar. Please add your updates directly to the question using [edit] rather than putting them in comments. If you can give us a [mcve] demonstrating the failure, it would be a lot easier to debug.

Comment: check what is on row 31 and the dimensions of the objects involved

Comment: The size of `rho` grows with each iteration. For `i == 2`, `rho` is a 1x2 vector and since all other values in `N` are scalars, it no longer fits. You can put a breakpoint at that line and check the values before it executes to see what's going on.